# Why is my PHP array not entering a function as not being empty?

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, I am running an `if statement` if my array is empty.

For example:

```
$csv = array();

$csv_empty = array_filter($csv);

if (!empty($csv_empty)) 
{
    Other code goes here
}

unset($csv);
```

Unfortunately, my `if statement` is not being entered at all. Here is a dump of my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1@foo.com
            [1] => email2@foo.com
            [2] => email3@foo.com
        )

)
```

If needed, this is how my array is being created, via a CSV file upload (This is NOT the if statement I am reffering to. This `if` statement runs perfectly fine without the other empty array checking `if` statement):

```
if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) 
{
    $row = 0;

    while (($result = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
    {
        $csv[] = $result;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Anyone have any idea to why my `if statement` is not running? Is it possibly because my array is 2 levels? If I changed my array to single level, would this fix my problem?

Comment: if($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE)

Comment: @zod - But that part runs absolutely fine without my `if statement` in place? Once I added the `if statement` around everything, it then stopped working.

Comment: If the array is changed from the callback function (e.g. element added, deleted or unset) the behavior of this function is undefined.

Comment: what is your purpose of using array_filter

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$csv_empty` after applying the filter.

Comment: @zod - Saw it in another post. Was recommended since it removes all unwanted parts in an array was as zeros.

Comment: And @zod, the code you posted is the exact same as the one I have.. Although yours returns an error since it is missing a bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have provided , I did not see any problem :

```
$csv = array( 0 => array( 0 => 'email1@foo.com' ,1 => 'email2@foo.com' ,2 => 'email3@foo.com' ) );

$csv_empty = array_filter( $csv );

if( ! empty( $csv_empty ) )
    echo 'In If';
else
    echo 'In Else';
```

Displays :

```
In If
```

But if I consider the array to have `false` s as the items , the get filtered by the `array_filter` :

```
$csv = array( 0 => false ,1 => false);

$csv_empty = array_filter( $csv );

if( ! empty( $csv_empty ) )
    echo 'In If';
else
    echo 'In Else';
```

Displays

```
In Else
```

> I am thinking your problem might somewhere else probably with the data .

Comment: Before I wrapped my code in that `if` statement that is checking whether the array is empty or not, the program worked seamlessly. So the data must be fine.

Comment: Would me `unsetting` the array afterwards cause any problems with this?

Comment: Unsetting the array afterwards could not create problem before . Just in case are you using any `callback` function ? Also try testing with  `display_errors` On .

Comment: Nup, no callback function. And even when I remove the `unsetting` of the array, it still won't enter that `if` statement. Would there be any other factors?

Comment: If I change the `if statement` to `if(empty($csv_empty))`, it seems to enter it for some reason...

Comment: In that case , test by avoiding `array_filter` , may be it is creating issues .

Comment: Still no luck. When I test it with `if(empty($csv_empty))`, and I refresh the page, the array doesn't seem to be unsetting... Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump( $csv_empty );` before and after the `array_filter` line ? Make sure it have values after `array_filter` .

Answer (score 0):

You should really use count($csv_empty)>0 instead of empty in that if.